# Filter not connected 2 tables but connected with another table

Tags: powerbi

I have 3 tables.
Table A - supplier name & Table B - Supplier name connected with DistSupplierName Table.
Question: I want to filter Supplier Duns(Tbl B) when i filter Expiration_Date(Tbl A)

[image]

Comment: Insufficient information.  We'd need to know how all 3 tables relate (the fields) ; the cardinality  and what you've tried.  It may be a simple as two inner joins.  between the 3 tables. it may be left joins between A--> DistSupplierName-->B... we just lack info to know.  Sample data and expected results would help as well: a Minimally Complete Verifiable Example (MCVE)

Answer (score 0):

As per your current data model,

DistSupplierName can filter tbl A cause filter direction is `DistSupplierName->tbl A`, meaning if you perform aggregation on `tblA` is visible to `DistSupplierName` but not the opposite.

DistSupplierName can filter tbl B cause filter direction is `DistSupplierName->tbl B`, meaning if you perform aggregation on `tblB` is visible to `DistSupplierName` but not the opposite.

If you want the aggregation of `tbl B` to be available to `tbl A`, i.e. filter `tbl B` by `tbl A`, you need to make the filter between DistSupplierName and tbl A bidirectional, i.e. `DistSupplierName<->tbl A`

Once it is done, what ever aggregation is done on `b` is visible to `DistSupplierName` and `tbl A` can access that with the bidirectional filter from `DistSupplierName`

But activating bidirectional filter also introduces some ambiguous paths in the data model and you need to exercise caution and validation in your calculation.